# How can I optimize my user/password table?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

For a uni project I'm looking at leaked usernames and passwords. I have roughly 275 million rows in my table.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    username varchar(300),
    password varchar(300)
);
```

PostgreSQL 10 runs on a ubuntu 18.04 VM with 5 cores and 50GB RAM. The DB will only be accessed from 1 or two people.

Relevant parts of config file:

```
max_connections = 100 
shared_buffers = 1024MB
work_mem = 512MB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix
```

When I try to run this query it takes more than 1h after which I cancel the query.

```
SELECT password, COUNT(*) AS amount FROM table GROUP BY password HAVING COUNT(*)>50000 ORDER BY amount DESC;
```

I'm now creating an index on username and when it's done I'll do the same for the password column.

Index creation:

```
CREATE INDEX pw_index ON table (password);
CREATE INDEX user_index ON table (username);
```

Explain result: https://explain.depesz.com/s/5KVW

What other things should I look for to optimize this table / database?

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: Are you the only one using this host?

Comment: The DB will only be accessed from 1 or two people. Added this to the initial post too

Comment: Please include the info outlined at https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: I've added more information in my initial post.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Any particular reason that, having 50 GB memory on the server, you only allocate 1 GB for shared buffers and .5 GB for sorts (work_mem)? Clearly, disk I/O and hash aggregate performance will be your bottlenecks.

Comment: Did you try `set max_parallel_workers_per_gather=4;`?